# "mount: wrong fs type.." error when mounting USB

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I'm stuck trying to mount a USB drive on a Raspberry Pi (Wheezy).  I've reformatted it (ext4) and tried re-mounting it in `/media/owncloud` (following `sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/owncloud`), but hit an error with the mount:

```
pi@raspberrypi /media $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/owncloud -o uid=pi,gid=pi -t ext4
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

pi@raspberrypi /media $ dmesg | tail
[   39.484660] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   47.116854] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[  310.473774] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
[  732.929020] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 1220.278044] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
[ 1331.002350] FAT-fs (sda1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 1331.002394] FAT-fs (sda1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2050.397804] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
[ 7973.889779] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
[ 8019.644801] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
```

Any idea what's causing this?  I've tried one solution elsewhere (`sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sda1`) which resulted in:

```
/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 11/493856 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 68109/1974271 blocks
```

..but didn't fix the issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `-o uid=pi,gid=pi` with `ext4`; the following should work:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/owncloud -t ext4
```

The `uid` and `gid` options are intended for filesystems which don't track ownership themselves (FAT for example). `ext4` is a POSIX filesystem and keeps its own information about file ownership, so it doesn't need (and can't use) `uid` and `gid` options.

Comment: Spot on cheers!